# Re-map the DOM for AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, lightbox

I'm loading a form using Nivo Lightbox AJAX.

```
form#users-add
```

Now I use another AJAX function to submit the form:

```
var users_add = $('#users-add');
users_add.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: users_add.attr('method'),
        url: users_add.attr('action'),
        data: users_add.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'users-add-success') {
                $('#users-add-cbk').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Utilisateur ajouté!</div>');
                users_add[0].reset();
            } else {
                $('#users-add-cbk').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Une erreur c\'est produite.</div>');
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#users-add-cbk').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Une erreur c\'est produite.</div>');
        },
    });
});
```

The problem here is that I have to re-map the DOM as `form#users-add` wasn't there when the the document has been fully loaded.

How to properly make the `form#users-add` seen by the script?

Comment: Use event delegation. `$(document).on("submit", "#users-add", ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m I tired $(document).on('submit', '#users-add', function() { but it still sends directly not through AJAX.

Comment: I can't see *anywhere* in your question that states it sends directly - only that you couldn't see the form.  I'd suggest raising a new question, but that would be a duplicate as well:  change your button from `<button type='submit'` to `<button type='button'` - the `e.preventDefault()` should stop it but doesn't seem to in this case.